# Is clCreateBuffer not device-specific?

Tags: opencl

The [clCreateBuffer function](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateBuffer.html) takes a context identifier but no device identifier; and a clContext [may](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateContext.html) have multiple devices.

Does that mean that OpenCL buffers are not device-specific? Or can contexts only contain devices which share a single physical memory space? Or perhaps I'm just missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buffers are not device specific, only context specific. And therefore, they can be used in all the devices that are part of the CL context.
This makes it possible to run OpenCL kernels where each kernel runs in a different GPU.

If your question is: "Ok, but where does the memory actually reside?"
The answer is, "it is not clear".

It can reside in the Host, Device, or multiple devices. It will eventually reside in the device that needs it for the kernel execution. The CL API ensures consistency, but does not ensure the buffer will be located in a given position. The API will asynchronously copy the buffer to another device if it thinks that it is going to be needed there in the future.

You can however manually tell the API to move a buffer to a device with: `clEnqueueMigrateMemObject()`
But the API is free to move it again if needed by another kernel.

Comment: I haven't encountered any case where this automatic copy behaves in a bad manner. Most of the time the API does a great job moving buffers around. Obviously a proper event system + memory flags has to be used, otherwise the API may not understand when a buffer needs to be moved/updated or not.

Comment: The thing is, sometimes you just want a buffer on a device and no copying around of anything.

Comment: If no data migration is needed, you can always allocate buffer in ctx, which is bind to specific device and do memcpy by hand. And actually OpenCL isn't a low-lewel API, it's pretty high-level IMO.

Comment: @RomanArzumanyan: Remember I didn't say anything about copying. I don't want to copy anything, just allocate.

Comment: If devices have separate memories, they will do memcpy implicitly (unless driver is clever enough to route data via PCI-Express w/o copying from one GPU to another). Even if driver can do so, bus will be the bottleneck.